# When exactly does the :active pseudo class get applied

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, dom-events, pseudo-class

I was trying to use `querySelector` to find active elements in a page. I assumed that a handler bound to a mousedown event on the document would trigger *after* the event had bubbled its way back from the target, which means the `:active` pseudoclass should already be applied.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){

    console.log(document.querySelector("*:active"));// logs null

    // expected value was the target of the mousedown event, that is,
    console.log(e.target);

});
```

My question is: at what point exactly does the the `:active` pseudo-class apply? Note that when I log the value, the `mousedown` event has already triggered on the target.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/2/ for an example. An interesting thing to note here is that if you set a breakpoint within the handler, you can see the css rule I defined for `a:active` already applying, although `querySelector` is returning *null*

EDIT:

Credit goes to TJ for coming up with a much better [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/7/). The problem still stands though: in browsers other than IE and Chrome, how can I get an HTMLCollection of all active elements as they become active?

Comment: It doesn't log `null` to me, it logs the html element. And `e.target` logs the anchor.

Comment: @bfavaretto Perhaps this is a browser specific issue? I'm using Firefox. `e.target` does indeed log the anchor, but the first one logs *`null`*

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that as you're using `querySelector`, you're only getting the *first* active element. But your anchor is much further down the tree.

**Update**: Interesting, I'm not getting anything with Firefox or Opera, but I am with Chrome. The below are Chrome results. See more on that below.

Consider ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/3/)):

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler, false);
function handler(e){
    console.log(
        "event " + e.type + ": " +
        Array.prototype.join.call(document.querySelectorAll("*:active")));
}​
```

When I click the anchor, I see this in the console:

```
event mousedown: [object HTMLHtmlElement],[object HTMLBodyElement],[object HTMLDivElement],http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#
```

Note the URL at the end, which is the default `toString` for `HTMLAnchroElement` instances, which is triggered by the `join`.

Since [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) is required to return the elements in document order, if you want the most specific active element, you'd use the last one. Example ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/4/)):

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown",handler, false);

    function handler(e){
        var active = document.querySelectorAll("*:active");
        var specific = active && active.length && active[active.length-1];
        display("Most specific active element: " +
                (specific ? specific.tagName : "(none)"));
    }

    function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
})();
​
```

In my case (using Chrome), I see the tag name of the most specific element (the anchor if I click the link, etc.).

---

It seems like Chrome is following the spec and taht Firefox and Opera are not. From [Section 6.6.1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) of the CSS3 Selectors spec:

> The `:active` pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.

It seems to me that `:active` should therefore apply in the above. This assertion is backed up if we use this CSS:

```
*:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

...with this JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);

    function mouseDown(){
        var active = document.querySelectorAll("*:active");
        var specific = active && active.length && active[active.length-1];
        display("Mouse down: Most specific active element: " +
                (specific ? specific.tagName : "(none)"));
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        display("Mouse up");
    }

    function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
})();
```

[Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/7/)

With all three browsers I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Opera), the element gets a red background while the mouse is down, and goes white again when I release it; but the `mousedown` handler doesn't see the `:active` element in Firefox or Opera, just Chrome.

But I'm not a CSS specification lawyer. :-)

Comment: In my console, I see: `event mousedown: `. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @Asad: Interesting, seems to be a difference in the browsers. Chrome gives me the list.

Comment: @Asad: Even more interesting when you make the CSS `*:active { ... }` rather than `span:active` (not least because there are no spans in your fiddle). It gets applied *while* the mouse is down, but the handler still doesn't see it in `querySelector(All)`.

Comment: @Asad: Just updated. I'd say Chrome is, Firefox and Opera aren't. But that's my interpretation.

Comment: Yes, the `span` was an oversight when I was reducing my problem to an example. I originally had a span. I've already mentioned that behaviour in the question.

Comment: I dunno, the spec doesn't really define what "activated" means for a browser so much as to give an *example* of what it *could* mean. Maybe there's just a whole lot of inconsistency (although I'm not saying that's OK...). The Web API WG or CSSWG mailing list would be a nice place to ask.

Comment: @BoltClock: True, but the example I quoted from the spec is pretty clear: *"...between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it..."* The argument that `querySelector(All)` should be finding it is strengthened by the fact that Firefox and Opera *do* apply the pseudo-class while the mouse is down (see the [new] end of my answer).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is really weird. Try this: hold down the mouse on the anchor, then move your mouse away from it and release. The next time you click the anchor it will be the most specific target.

Comment: @Asad Weird indeed. It seems firefox can detect the active element on mouseup, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/tK67w/8/ (it will print "mouse down" because I'm using the same event handler, but it's firing on mouse up).

Comment: @bavaretto: Isn't that exactly when it *shouldn't* be active?

Comment: @Asad that's why it's weird! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be set after the frame has been rendered, or maybe after the current execution queue, that's at least the case with Firefox.

Got results using `setTimeout` without delay (works with `requestAnimationFrame` too):

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {

  setTimeout(_ => console.log(document.querySelectorAll(':active')));

});
```